# How to detect changes on multiple SQL server tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, etl

We have an issue where we need to send only changes made to certain columns and certain tables. We have a prod DB on one server A, which we can not run Jobs or procedures on. Then we have seperate server where we run Jobs and Stored Procedures, Server B. My question is what are some ways to automate detecting changes in prod db Server A tables?

CDC?
Compare Hashes?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely do not want to use triggers. The software vendor could/will find them and use it as an excuse to stop supporting your app.

Using CDC will not slow down the system (that much) and will not affect the mechanics of the app. There will be several system tables that will be created/affected by CDC but they will be in parallel to your app.

Comment: what if we copy the prod tables into another db daily?Will the table copies work with cdc??? or does cdc only work on prod and not a copy of prod?

Comment: if you set up cdc on another database you can set up cdc there too.  If you recreate a table  (by dropping and copying) you lose CDC. CDC is quite easy to set up but its not magic.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you cannot use triggers, i.e. on update or insert?

Since triggers won't work for you perhaps add insert and update timestamp columns to the tables you want to monitor. You could then maintain a list of timestamps of the times the diff check was run. Anything with a "new" insert or update timestamp would be something you would then export to the B server.

Comment: we can't create any triggers, stored procedures on prod server. It's a Medical Claim DB and we have limited say in what can be added. That's why we have our own server for running jobs and procedures

Comment: sorry, I did not mention we can not change table schema